# How to get correct position of a gameobject thatis inside a vertical Layout group in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, vertical-alignment

I have a vertical layout group containing 3 game object

[image]

[image]

when I try to get the correct position of the child Objects  from the vertical Layout group, it does not giving the correct output.
[image]

[image]

I tried

```
myPosition = this.gameObject.transform.localPosition;
myPosition = this.gameObject.transform.position;
myPosition = this.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position;
myPosition = this.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition;
```

Non gave the correct output. How to get this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to fetch the position in `Update` or `LateUpdate` method, don't do that in `Awake` or `Start`.

```
void Update()
{
    if(transform.hasChanged)
        myPosition = ((RectTransform)transform).anchoredPosition;
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UIAutoLayout.html

> The rebuild will not happen immediately, but at the end of the current frame, just before rendering happens.

---

According to the documentation above, you cannot freely trigger layout rebuild, so this way is just based on the order of layout calculations: Call these 4 methods before fetching the position.

```
// VerticalLayoutGroup vlg;
vlg.CalculateLayoutInputHorizontal();
vlg.SetLayoutHorizontal();
vlg.CalculateLayoutInputVertical();
vlg.SetLayoutVertical();
myPosition = ((RectTransform)transform).anchoredPosition;
```

Comment: actually i need to get it in the start

Comment: You can try my method, but no guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is correct!

You can actually even change the recttransform if you override SetLayoutVertical for example, like so:

```
public override void SetLayoutVertical()
    {
        base.SetLayoutVertical();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < rootRect.childCount; i++)
        {
            var childRect = rootRect.GetChild(i) as RectTransform;
            if (childRect == null || !childRect.gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
                continue;

            var relativeHeight = Math.Abs(childRect.anchoredPosition.y / rootRect.sizeDelta.y);
            var horizontalOffset = Mathf.Lerp(topOffset, bottomOffset, relativeHeight);
            // Debug.Log($"Relative height {childRect.anchoredPosition.y}/{rootRect.sizeDelta.y}={relativeHeight} and offset {horizontalOffset}");

            childRect.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(childRect.anchoredPosition.x + horizontalOffset, childRect.anchoredPosition.y);
        }
    }
```

This is example code to build a slanted vertical layout group, that adds an offset from topOffset to bottomOffset based on a child's position within its parent that has a content size fitter to always be the exact height as all children combined.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAIDh.png)